# I have to update a query with array as a string by using implode function but it is not working properly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to update a query with array as a string by using implode function

```
  public function add_students_who_travel_by_bus(){
    $select_bus_stop = $this->input->post('select_bus_stop');
          $checkbox = $this->input->post('checkbox[]');
            if($checkbox){
                $id = implode(",",$checkbox);
                    $data = array(
                    "student_id" => '$id', 
                    );
                    $this->db->where('transport_route_time_id',$select_bus_stop);
                    $this->db->update('transport_route_time',$data); 

              return $this->session->set_flashdata('response_message', '<div class="alert alert-info">Successfully Updated !</div>');
                }else{
                    return $this->session->set_flashdata('response_message', '<div class="alert alert-danger">Data Not Found To Store !</div>');
                }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'not working properly'? is it show some error? is it save a wrong values? is it no values saved?

Comment: it inserts only first index value of array

Comment: but when i echo $id it prints an string

Comment: checkout my snippet in answer section and try refer the name without '[]'. hopefully it can help you in some way.

Comment: i get the array in controller from view in $checkbox

Comment: ah now i understand.. let say the $checkbox values is array(11, 22, 33), then your $id value will be '11,22,33'. however it only saved 11 to your db right? this happen because your 'student_id' is 'int'. try to change it as varchar.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185081/discussion-between-hifebriansyah-and-tushar).

Answer (score 0):

by 'not working properly' did you mean there is no value saved? if it's that the case, try to

`var_dump($this->input->post('checkbox[]'));die();`

if it's null than maybe you use wrong name? please, share the html form, so i can give a better answer..

edited :

as far i remember, to get the checkbox values in codeigniter, you dont need to use '[]'

for example let sya you have these on your form

```
<input type="checkbox" name="businessType[]" value="1">
<input type="checkbox" name="businessType[]" value="2">
<input type="checkbox" name="businessType[]" value="3">
```

all you need to get the values is to refer 'businessType' (without '[]') as name.

```
$data = $this->input->post('businessType');
```